# catching error in loop sql query

Tags: sql, t-sql, while-loop

I have the below insert query which selects records from the OriginalData table where everything is nvarchar(max) and inserts it into the Temp table which has specific field definitions i.e MainAccount is INT.

I am doing a row by row insert because if there is a record in OriginalData table where the MainAccount value is 'Test' the it will obviously cause a conversion error and the insert will fail.

I want to be able to capture this error. There is a field on the originalData table called "error" which I want to populate. However I want this to run thru the entire table as oppose to fail on the first error and stop.

```
DECLARE @RowId INT
, @MaxRowId INT  

Set @RowId = 1
Select @MaxRowId = 60 

WHILE(@RowId <= @MaxRowId)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [Temp] (ExtractSource, MainAccount,RecordLevel1Code, RecordLevel2Code, RecordTypeNo, TransDate, Amount, PeriodCode, CompanyCode)

SELECT ExtractSource, MainAccount,RecordLevel1Code, RecordLevel2Code,RecordTypeNo,TransDate, Amount, PeriodCode, DataAreaId
FROM [OriginalData] 
WHERE RowId = @RowId

PRINT @RowId  
SET @RowId  = @RowId  + 1        
END
select * from [Temp]
```

Comment: Would `... where RowId = @RowId and MainAccount != 'Test'` reduce the errors from a predictable source? How much analysis will be in your `catch` block to determine the actual cause of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `TRY..CATCH` block:

```
WHILE(@RowId <= @MaxRowId)
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY  
    INSERT INTO [Temp] (ExtractSource, MainAccount,RecordLevel1Code,
      RecordLevel2Code, RecordTypeNo, TransDate, Amount, PeriodCode, CompanyCode)
    SELECT ExtractSource, MainAccount,RecordLevel1Code, RecordLevel2Code,
       RecordTypeNo,TransDate, Amount, PeriodCode, DataAreaId
    FROM [OriginalData] 
    WHERE RowId = @RowId;

    PRINT @RowId;

  END TRY  
  BEGIN CATCH  
    -- error handlingg
  END CATCH 
  SET @RowId += 1;      
END
```